# Avoid antialiasing in canvas element

Tags: canvas, antialiasing

I know that to avoid antialiasing effect in lines, I have to translate 0.5 px in the x and y coordinates.But this does not function in quadratic curves.
I need to draw a quadratic curve without having the effect of the antialiasing.
I need to draw letters with its coordinates x,y and the properties lineTo() and quadraticCurveTo(), but I do not want this letters to have antialiasing effect.

Answer (score 0):

**Sadly, you currently can't turn off anti-aliasing.**

The last time I checked whatWG was still thinking about adding this option, but so far no recommendation and no browser implements turning off anti-aliasing.

The closest we get is when drawing images:

```
context.imageSmoothingEnabled=false;  // see description below
```

Perhaps you can hack together something that uses drawImage() to render your letter-curves. I read somewhere that three.js uses this method to draw smoother curves--but memory fails about where.

*Description of imageSmoothingEnabled*

- Returns whether pattern fills and the drawImage() method will attempt to smooth images if their pixels don't line up exactly with the display.  Can be set, to change whether images are smoothed (true) or not (false). See ( http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#image-smoothing);